# NaN comparison rule in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, nan

Doing some optimziation on a piece of code, the correctness of the code depending on how the compiler handle NaNs.

I read the IEEE-754 rules on NaN, which states:

> The comparisons EQ, GT, GE, LT, and LE, when either or both operands
>   is NaN returns FALSE.
>
> The comparison NE, when either or both operands is NaN returns TRUE.

Are the above rules enforced in C/C++?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C/C++ does not require specific floating-point representation and does not require that any comparison against `NaN` is `false`.

In C++ you can check if all floating-point types fulfill IEEE 754 using `std::numeric_limits::is_iec559`:

> `static constexpr bool is_iec559;`
>
> <sup>56</sup> True if and only if the type adheres to IEC 559 standard.<sup>217</sup>
>
> <sup>57</sup> Meaningful for all floating point types.
>
> ---
>
> 217) International Electrotechnical Commission standard 559 is the same as IEEE 754.

For other floating-point representations comparison against `NaN` 
may or may not behave the same way.

In fact, even representing `NaN` itself is not required. See [`std::numeric_limits<T>::has_quiet_NaN`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/has_quiet_NaN), 
[`std::numeric_limits<T>::has_signaling_NaN`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/has_signaling_NaN).

Comment: This is a bit misleading. The question does not ask about IEC 559 in general, it asks about one specific aspect of that standard, which may or may not be guaranteed by the C and C++ standards directly even on implementations that disregard IEC 559.

Comment: The standard says that "Two values (other than NaNs) with the same object representation compare equal" though.

Comment: @a3f Yes, but that by itself leaves unspecified whether two NaNs with the same object representation also compare equal.

Comment: @hvd I think the point is that if it disregards IEC559, the standard doesn't specify any requirements -- they may or may not compare equal. You can only depend on the results if it supports IEC559.

Comment: @hvd Agreed, reworded a bit.

Comment: I think there is one requirement on NaNs when an implementation does not follow IEC 559, at least in C: 6.5.9 Equality operators (`==` and `!=`): "For any pair of operands, exactly one of the relations is true." This disallows implementations from treating NaNs similarly to SQL NULLs which compare neither equal nor unequal to themselves.

Comment: @hvd Good point. FWIW the `C++` standard conspicuously omits the `For any pair of operands, exactly one of the relations is true` part at 5.10 *Equality operators*.

Answer (score 17):

The `==` and `!=` operators appear to *not* be constrained to the `IEEE 754` behavior for `NaN`s, as pointed out in @AlexD's answer already.

However, the `<math.h>` comparison macros *are* required to follow `NaN` rules equivalent to `IEEE 754`'s. The following from the `C11` draft N1580 under 7.12.14 *Comparison Macros* states that the `<math.h>` comparison macros *are* required to ensure that, if either or both of `x, y` are `NaN`s then:

- `isunordered(x, y)` is `true`
- `isgreater(x, y)`, `isgreaterequal(x, y)`, `isless(x, y)`, `islessequal(x, y)` are all `false`

> The  relational  and  equality  operators  support  the  usual  mathematical  relationships between  numeric  values.  For  any **ordered** pair  of  numeric  values  exactly  one  of  the relationships - `less`, `greater`, and `equal` - is true.  Relational operators may raise the "invalid" floating-point  exception  when  argument  values  are  `NaN`s. **For a `NaN`  and  a numeric value, or for two `NaN`s, just the unordered relationship is true**.

The `C++` standard simply defers to the `C` one on `<math.h>` matters:

> The classiﬁcation/comparison functions behave the same as the C macros with the corresponding names
>   deﬁned in 7.12.3, Classiﬁcation macros, and 7.12.14, Comparison macros in the C Standard.