# static_assert doesn't fire on MSVC

Tags: c++, compile-time, static-assert

The below example code fires the "testing" assert with gcc and clang, but not MSVC. Only when the line marked `comment this out` is commented out does it fire. With GCC and clang it fires both with and without that line. Is that expected?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool B>
constexpr void issue_error()
{
    static_assert(B, "testing");
};

int main()
{
    issue_error<false>();
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int,char>,"!!"); // comment this out
}
```

Comment: It fails on [godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/Gqhn4zndz). Oh. You mean it doesn't fire when the line is made a comment? Hm.

Comment: I don't think the standard says anything about the order the compiler has to evaluate things. Apparently, if main() already fails at the first level MSVC doesn't bother to also compile the call to the next level. Should it?

Comment: Possible duplicate (is a bit old) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246049/c11-static-assert-and-template-instantiation

Comment: gcc with -fmax-errors=1 behaves like MSVC. (Although MSVC does not by default stop after the first error, but perhaps it does with static assertions -- that would make some sense and save compile time for useless builds.)

Comment: I am not sure, but it might be related to a bug I found last year: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66420107

Comment: @RichardCritten That is about no possible valid instantiation, which clearly `issue_error<true>` is.