# MSVC 2022 wrong optimization of max(NaN, someNumber)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

Considering that MSVC guarantees IEEE 754 ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/ieee-floating-point-representation?view=msvc-170)):

Using the `max` macro from `Windows.h` (in a legacy codebase) seems to yield incorrect codegen on MSVC 2022 with optimizations enabled.

The issue arises when the first argument to `max` is `NaN`: `max(nan, 1)`, expanding to `nan > 1 ? nan : 1`, should yield 1, since `nan > whatever` is always false.
The result is as expected for all compilers except MSVC under the following cirsumstances:

- MSVC 2022 (2019 works fine)
- Not constant-evaluated (constexpr result is as expected)
- Optimizations enabled (`/O1` or `/O2`)
- Expression result is assigned to the same variable that holds the `NaN`

MSVC optimizes the expression to the constant value `NaN`, which is incorrect (right?).

**See https://godbolt.org/z/oMGqWoj46**

Code sample:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>

// Problem doesn't arise with std::max
// Definition taken straight out of minwindef.h
#define my_max( a, b ) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))

constexpr double get()
{
    double value = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    value = my_max( value, 1 ); // (nan > anything) is false, so should be 1
    return value;
}

static_assert( get() == 1 ); // As expected

int main()
{
    // MSVC 2022 with /O1 or /O2 outputs nan
    // MSVC 2019, 2022 without optimizations, and all other compilers output 1
    std::printf( "%f\n", get() );
}
```

**Question:** Is this bad codegen, or is there some UB hiding somewhere?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38798823/4117728

Comment: I think it is at least implementation defined. You should first check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/has_quiet_NaN

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! Though, to play devil's advocate, doesn't MSVC guarantee IEEE 754? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/ieee-floating-point-representation?view=msvc-170)