# could the type of std::map's key be double or float?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I've writed a test case:

```cpp
//environment: compiler=msvc140-x64 system=win10
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::map<double, std::string> mapd2str;

    double dval1 = 1;
    mapd2str[dval1] = std::to_string(dval1);

    double dval2 = 1 + 1e-6;
    mapd2str[dval2] = std::to_string(dval2);

    for (auto& p : mapd2str)
    {
        std::cout << "first=" << p.first << ", second=" << p.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the output is as follow:

```
first=1, second=1.000000
first=1.00001, second=1.000010
```

after I changed the dval2 to `1 + 10e-20`, the output is as follow:

```
first=1, second=1.000000
```

**so, if I use the double or float as the key of std::map, is there any risk?**

Comment: What does "risk" mean?

Comment: 1 + 10e-20 is 1 because 10e-20 is 1e-19 is less than std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon().

Comment: Yes you can. Just make sure you understand the limits of floating point numbers and what that means. The equality test for looking up keys requires an exact match (which could be an issue). But looping over a map should work just fine . Note be careful printing floats with `std::cout` it does not always print all the digits.

Comment: the risk is: if I do not  know the precision of the key that wll be inserted to the map, the program will not run as I expected.

Comment: ok, thanks to  Martin York

Comment: Can the key be not-a-number (`std::nan("")`)?  If so, you'll need your own comparator to be well ordered.

Comment: @Eljay you're thoughtful~

Comment: Positive and negative 0.0 is another potential problem area, because `0.0 == -0.0`. If you start with an empty map, for example, then the second of these assignment will overwrite the first: `mapd2str[0.0] = "positive zero"; mapd2str[-0.0] = "negative zero";`. You end up with only one element in the map.

Comment: @tbxfreeware thanks, I decide to implement my own comparator for the map or set.

Comment: @Eljay yeah, NaN are such `a` values that  `a<a`, `a==a`, and `a>a` are `false` at same time, I'm not even sure what `map` would do in that case, that's an UB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you refer to as "risk". The `std::map` is totally fine with `float` or `double` as keys.

A risk might be that keys you expect to be identical are not and that keys you expect to be different are in fact identical. `1 + 10e-20` is the same `double` as `1.0` because `double` has finite precision. There are other cases where intuition fails. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more details. Though, I repeat, the map has no issue with floating numbers as keys. If you insert a value for key `0.123` and later search for the value with key `0.123` you will find the right value. There is no risk in that.

If you do write a custom comparator, make sure it implements a strict weak ordering. The usual epsilon comparison of floating point numbers cannot do that! Also `inf` and `nan` require to take care when implementing the comparator.

Comment: Inf and -Inf should be fine, because they are well-ordered

Comment: @Caleth they are fine with `<` but not necessarily with their custom comparator

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai could you show me a correct example of floating point numbers comparator which is strict-weak-ordering?

Comment: @cfersX you didnt reply to whether you need to be able to handle `nan`, if not simply use built in `<`. If yes, you need to consider this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798791/nan-comparison-rule-in-c-c